# what is browser in user point of view and developer point of view?

Tags: browser, web-deployment-project

I have a question. Can anyone please answer me. I got this question from my friend.
what is browser in user point of view and developer point of view?

Answer (score 1):

> what is browser in user point of view and developer point of view?

This is what an end-user will see:

[image]

This is what a developer will see:

[image]

Comment: developer probably has 700 tabs open, but +1 ;-)

Comment: Can you explain in detail please?

Answer (score 0):

hit f12 in your browser to  bring up developer tools. from there you can see the CSS/HTML etc. used (if in IE after pressing f12, click the little mouse pointer that appears then hover over/click any element on the page to bring up the CSS/HTML for that part of the page).

EDIT

a user can't see the markup for the page, just the finished product. Using developer tools  allows you to see how the page was put together. When you bring up developer tools, it shows the HTML for the page on the left and the CSS for the page on the right, you can edit the HTML and turn off/on parts of the CSS to change the look of the page. Hope this helps. I tried adding a picture but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail please?